# Pass GET to other view Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm developing a component (backend). I got a listview with a $_GET that contains a `ID number`
and i want to send the $_GET to the add view

```
(JToolBarHelper::addNew('item.add', 'JTOOLBAR_NEW');)
```

But i don't find any good solution on this, i have inserted the value in listviews form, but i am not possible to take it out. I tried to create a add function in the controller for my add/edit view but is dosen't work. Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I managed to find one solution for this, if send the ID number with post, then i'm available to get the data from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider [JApplication/JSession like this](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables#Why_should_I_use_the_Joomla.21_User_State_Variables.3F)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.